# Git, RVM, Ruby and Rails on OSX Tiger

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, macos, git, bash, rvm

I have an old laptop which runs **OSX 10.4 Tiger** where I'd like to run **git, rvm, Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1**.

At the moment **I have git installed** (using MacPorts), but **rvm seems to require a newer version of bash**. This I realized because the install script complains and I googled the error. Anyhow, I installed a newer bash with MacPorts and that helped me with getting rvm installed. However, it of course didn't replace the default bash version on the system and all rvm scripts point to the system one. This simply results in failures when I try to run any rvm commands.

Before I totally mess up the system I'd like to know **does anyone have git, rvm, Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1 installed on OSX 10.4 Tiger?** How did you install each part and what versions do you use?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: I do not, but wouldn't a simple `chsh`be enough to change your default shell?

Comment: This will not affects scripts that point to specific versions of scripts on the first line e.g. #!/bin/bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got this to work, but I decided to upgrade to OSX Snow Leopard. After this it was very easy to get things set up. This is what I recommend.